# Class instances differ, which one to use?

Tags: objective-c, class, ipad, instance

I'm stuck with the following. In a program, I'm trying to communicate between different classes (View Controllers with NIB files attached in a TabBar application etc). I want to call a method 'OMFG' in a class called 'ProductViewDetailController'. This class is a UIViewController (SplitViewDelegate). It's loaded programmatically.

Anyways, I've been trying to get the right call to this controller, and I came up with 2 solutions. One is declaring the productviewdetailcontroller in the caller's .h file and .m file, making an IBOutlet, linking it in the Interface builder and calling it directly by the line

```
[productDetailController OMFG];
```

When I call this method, it calls the right method in the ProductViewDetailController, but the instance of this viewcontroller differs from the one I programmatically can reach with this code:

```
for (UIViewController *controller in self.tabBarController.viewControllers) {
      NSLog(@"%@", [controller class]);
      if ([controller isKindOfClass:[UISplitViewController class]]) {
       UISplitViewController *cell = (UISplitViewController *)controller;
       for (UIViewController *controller2 in cell.viewControllers) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [controller2 class]);
        if ([controller2 isKindOfClass:[ProductViewDetailController class]]) {
         [controller2 OMFG];

        }
       }
      }
```

Which one should I use, and why?

edit: When I try to add a SubView to both viewcontrollers, the one where the call is [controller2 OMFG]; actually shows the newly added view, where the [productDetailController OMFG]; doesn't show the newly added view... Why is that? Is there a shorter (and more chique) way to get access to the right ViewController?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `IBOutlet`. This makes sure your app can still call the correct target if you later decide to change the hierarchy of view controllers, for example if creating an iPhone compatible setup without a `UISplitViewController`.

Calling `isKindOfClass:` in Objective-C is a sure sign that what you are doing is probably wrong. Firstly in Cocoa Touch *what you do* is always more important than *who you are*. Secondly what you try to do is probably peeking inside something that should be left private.

Comment: Hmm interesting. Because I create the view programmatically, doesn't it override the link to the instance class in the Interface Builder file? As said, when I tried adding a subview in the method OMFG, one did show the subview and one didn't.. Or am I linking the Outlet to the instance in a wrong manner..

Comment: You override `loadView`? If you do you **must not** call the super implementation.

Comment: Nope, well I'm recreating the target (SplitViews in TabBars) programmatically because Apple doesn't support SplitViews in a Tab Bar construction (like this: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/49491-uisplitview-tabbar-question.html)